# How to solve $\tan^2x + \tan^2{2x} + \cot^2{3x} =1$

Tags: trigonometry

How to solve $\tan^2x + \tan^2{2x} + \cot^2{3x} =1$?

I've tried to use some formulas and I've written that 
[image]

but it didn't make much easier. The derivative is  ugly too.

 Mayby there is a simple way?

Comment: Do we have to differentiate? Or just prove LHS = RHS

Comment: There do not seem to be any real solutions

Comment: I know there is not any solution, so how to prove that?

Comment: You can add where the problem is from (try to be detailed, if it is possible add links to the book or pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u = \tan(x)$.

Using the equation you found, we can write:

$u^2 + \frac{4u^2}{(1-u^2)^2} + \frac{(1-3u^2)^2}{(3u - u^3)^2} = 1$

Simplifying, we get:

$u^{12} - 9 u^{10} + 43 u^8 - 94 u^6 + 91 u^4 - 17 u^2 + 1 = 0$

Finding the [Sturm chain](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4087390/905694) of the above polynomial, we see that there is no change in sign, thus implying that there are no real roots to the above equation.

Comment: Ok, so is it only that method?

Comment: @piteer Perhaps there is a simpler method, but I could only come up with this!